# Array Traversal in C#

Tags: c#, python, arrays

My question is whether or not in C# is there a method to traverse through an array like that of Python.

For instance in Python

```
arr = [1 , 2, 3 , 4, 5]
print (arr[3:])
arr[3:] = [7, 8]
print (arr[3:])
```

Would give me an output of [4, 5] and then [7,8].

I was wondering if there exists something of the sort in C# as well. I went through most of the documentation at MSDN Microsoft and other links but I found the traditional for loops and for each loops. I was maybe hoping I missed it and someone has the answer I'm looking since I didn't find it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No...

```
print (arr[3:])
```

In C# There is no short notation for getting a subset of an array.

```
arr[3:] = [7, 8]
```

And there is no short notation for replacing a piece of an array with another array (or for copying an array to another array)

There is the [ArraySegment<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) class for creating a view on a subset of an array, or you can use the LINQ [Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)/[Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the same. Still no short notation and no copying/replacing.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll stick to loops. Thanks for the ArraySlice information but since i'm doing a circular array rotation problem I'll need some copying to be done. I'll keep a reference to ArraySlice for any possible future use.

Comment: @HaroonRamay There was an initial discussion about adding array slices to C# 7.0, but I think the idea was abandoned.

Comment: Really hope they add it in future editions because I think it'll make life lot more easier. Also could you please point towards the link where discussions can viewed for future editions of C# if any.

Comment: @HaroonRamay https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/120 and https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/98

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble Having searched for ArraySlice in the MSDN documentation and not finding anything for ArraySlice. I believe the link was meant to point towards ArraySegment.

Comment: @HaroonRamay it was. Just mislabelled.

Comment: Yep corrected... I had the right link but the wrong label :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do similar things with a *functional approach*

```
var arr = new int[]{1 , 2, 3 , 4, 5}; 
var arr2 = arr.Skip (2).ToArray ();
var arr3 = arr.Take (3).Concat(new int[]{7,8}).ToArray ();


 Console.WriteLine  (String.Join(",",arr));
 Console.WriteLine  (String.Join(",",arr2));      
 Console.WriteLine  (String.Join(",",arr3));
```

The output

```
1,2,3,4,5
3,4,5
1,2,3,7,8
```

Comment: Thank you, your example helped out a lot with the syntactical issues and the Concat Function was extremely useful. Sorry for the delay I was caught up in school work and procrastination.